# Booting back to Winows 10 via Grub2 command-line

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am trying to get my PC get back to Windows 10 boot by typing in the following at `grub>`:

```
 chainloader (hd0,gpt2)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi grub>boot
```

It returns `incorrect command, syntax error`
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you have an UEFI install, you should be able to boot directly from UEFI boot menu, often f12 but check your manual. Should be same key you used to select to boot USB flash drive to install Ubuntu.

Comment: You should be booting from the grub menu, not the grub prompt. That's the main purpose of having grub as a boot manager.  If you're getting the prompt when you boot, then grub needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If all is well you should see the Windows partition in the grub bootloader. This question seems to be a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why did you have to issue the command in the first place?

From there you could select the partition and windows starts... If that works you could - if you wish - configure your grub to start the windows partition by default- but that's another question.

If you do not see that windows partition you might have to setup grub again. In this case you should observe the output of the installation process and find a clue why it didn't work. You could [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252177/edit) your question and paste the result of the installation process there.